# Unable to add platform ionic platform add Android

Tags: ionic-framework

Getting below error when running command **ionic platform add android**

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory _____\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.1\VERSION'
```

Comment: Can you please run the following and include the answers in your question: 'ionic -v', 'cordova -v'.  I want to know what versions of the CLI you're using.  Also please let us know your operating system.  It looks like Windows, but I could be wrong.

Comment: We need more information about your issue. It might be a path issue that is bit set properly, a permission problem on your phonegap directory...

Comment: Please search first

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful

Answer (score 0):

I am providing step by step installation of ionic along with cordova.
Have a look it may help you :

1. First install node to get started using [this](https://nodejs.org/en/) link
2. open cmd to install [cordova](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/27/what-is-cordova-and-how-does-it-work/) using following command
   $ sudo npm install -g cordova
   (Drop sudo from the above command if running on Windows)
3. install ionic using command 
   $ sudo npm install -g ionic
4. Create project after selecting directory where project file will be stored,
   through CMD,by following command
   ionic start {project name} {template type} e.g
   ionic start todo blank
5. Once your project is created go to your newly created project: cd .\new project. for e.g.
   D:\Projects>cd.\todo
6. Now you have to add both android and ios to your project in order to test the build so you need to follow below commands

   **ionic cordova platform add android**

   **ionic cordova platform add ios**

I think in your case you are missing step 5.