# Cordova - ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions

Tags: android, node.js, cordova

I've installed nodejs and cordova and downloaded android sdk. The thing is when I try and add an android platform here's what sortf happen:

```
$ sudo cordova platform add android
Creating android project...
/home/blurt/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package    /bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
```

None of the solutions that I found in the Internet worked.

When I type :

```
$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

it gives nothing.

When I type:

```
 echo $PATH
```

it prints

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:  /usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform- tools:/opt/node/bin:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/node/bin
```

shows this.

I believe my SDK path is `:/opt/android-sdk/tools`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created the *ANDROID_HOME* environmental variable for your system. You should add it on the environmental variables by hand for example with method specified by *mach* on [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356482/1744702).

Comment: thanks for fixing the question..
still not working, I've tried the answer thats posted in the link, but it didnt work. I guess Im using the wrong path

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the path to android sdk in `ANDROID_HOME`. The path needs to be till the root folder of the sdk or `/opt/android-sdk/` in your case.

Add the following to your ~/.bashrc file.

```
# Android Path
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk:$HOME/Documents/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH
```

Then do a `source ~/.bashrc` to reload bashrc

Comment: how can I achieve this exactly? should I edit bashrc or profile file?

Comment: @EnderCode That is just a dummy value.. you should replace `/Documents/Android/sdk ` with your own path