# cordova build android throws error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, cordova

The issue looks very familiar with this
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

But I am not able to fix it.  When I run

```
% sudo cordova build android
```

I am getting the following error

```
Running command:   /home/thabung/mobile/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/thabung/mobile/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /home/thabung/mobile/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Few things I am observing

```
 % echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

returns me

```
 ~/mobile/android-sdk-linux
```

which is perfect location
& android command also works fine. 
Please help..
I am using cordova 4.3.0

Comment: Why are you running `sudo cordova build android` and not `cordova build android`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ...

```
sudo cordova build android
```

runs in the environment of *root* whereas this ...

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

was not executed as *root*. Check what `echo $ANDROID_HOME` returns as *root* - or (strongly recommended) - run Cordova as another user than *root*.

***p.s.***: I'm running Cordova 4.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 without `sudo`.