# Phonegap error in adding android platform in ubuntu

Tags: android, cordova

While i try to add an android platform in my Phonegap project i get this error

```
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist':Error: <project_path>/platforms/android/cordova/version: Command failed with exit code EACCES
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:818:12)
```

And i try do some of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409541/cordova-build-command-failed-with-exit-code-eacces) solutions like give permission to build and remove the android platform and add it again but every time i get the same error

What is the potential solution ?

Comment: Did you install as `root` and try to add as a normal user?

Comment: sudo phonegap platform add android

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html) there is no need to run `cordova platform add android` as `root`. Check the example:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cd hello
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova build
```

If you still face any issue check that executable scripts or programs are allowed to be executed.

In your case I'd guess that `cordova` tries to run

```
<project_path>/platforms/android/cordova/version
```

what is probably not allowed to be executed. So call

```
sudo chmod ugo+x <project_path>/platforms/android/cordova/version
```

to make `version` executable.

***p.s.*:** updated my answer above. Some days ago I tested for [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29461081/cordova-build-android-throws-error-on-ubuntu-12-04) what happens, if I added the platform as `root`. Though it was another issue there I saw that it is not required to run `cordova platform add android` as `root`.

I think it's only the basic installation of Cordova that requires `root`. Everything else should be set up and executed as a normal user.

Comment: Is this after adding ?

because when i call "phonegap platforms ls" it returns 

"Installed platforms: android broken"

Comment: Ok, I double checked it: usually there is no need to run `cordova platform add android` as `root`. May be you got errors due to the fact that you added is as `root`. I'll update my answer accordingly ...

Comment: (( $ phonegap build ))

i get this error

"Command failed with exit code EACCES
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project"

Comment: When i call "phonegap platform add android" without root it returns Platform android already added. but its broken, and i try to delete android from platform and add it again without root also it return the same error above in the question

Comment: Did you check the _executable_-flag of `<project_path>/platforms/android/cordova/version`? See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7033: _"One way is for a script/file which your version script depends on to go missing/lose its execute bit. ..."_

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem but i work on linux/ubuntu and i try to create an application at Home, and that issues disappeared, i think is depends on permission or mounting the disk!.