# PhoneGap Cordova Build Error Exit Code 2

Tags: android, cordova

I'minstalled PhoneGap and made one simple app that works on my tablet when using PhoneGap server and PhoneGap App for android. Now I want to makean APK but I'm gatting error when run`sudo phonegap build android` in APP folder:

> miljan@Miljan-PC:~/Desktop/HelloWorld$ sudo phonegap build android
>   [sudo] password for miljan:  [phonegap] executing 'cordova build
>   android'... cp: no such file or directory:
>   /home/miljan/Desktop/HelloWorld/icon.png
>
> Running command:
>   /home/miljan/Desktop/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/build
>
> [Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your
>   PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.]
>
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error:
>   /home/miljan/Desktop/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2 You may not have the required
>   environment or OS to build this project
>
> Error:
>   /home/miljan/Desktop/HelloWorld/platforms/android/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 2
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
>       at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)

In ~/.profile I have add this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/miljan/Android-SDK-Linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```

How I can slove this problem?
Anyone who can help?

Comment: Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I was using ionic to build android. I used this solution to solve my problem

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

use the third solution and don't use the exact paths which are given here. In the android_home give the path of your sdk. in the android_tools give the path of tools in the sdk and in the third give the platform path given in the sdk.

and if you have problem after this too user**chmod 777 /sdk/tools** and **chmod 777 /sdk/tools/android**.

May this solution helps