# Meteor 1.2 error "Android SDK not found" when building android app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

After updating to meteor 1.2, I am not able to get my app to build for android. I have followed the instructions on https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-Mac to the end.

I get the following error when I run `meteor run android-device --verbose` :

```
Getting installed version for platform android in Cordova project
Getting installed version for platform ios in Cordova project
Checking Cordova requirements for platform Android

Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for
Android.

Please follow the installation instructions here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Development-Install:-Android-on-    Mac

Status of the requirements:                   
✓ Java JDK                                    
✓ Android SDK                                 
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✓ Gradle
```

I have run `rm -rf .meteor/local`, `export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sd`, `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-toolsexport ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk`, i even set the environment in the server as `process.env.ANDROID_HOME = '~/Library/Android/sdk';`.

I am not sure how to get this to work, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@junior try giving the complete path of the android sdk...i hope this works...and see if the requirements match...because, it does say all the requirements don't match.....

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\\android-sdk-windows
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

MAC
    export ANDROID_HOME="/Users//Library/Android/sdk/"
    export ANDROID_TOOLS="/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools"
    export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-        tools"
    PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_TOOLS:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS
and again try re-installing
    $ android
and then go to a Cordova-based project directory
    $ ionic platform add android

or try this link
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

Comment: I have tried to add the full path and that didn't work, also, the requirement that is missing is the one with the cross and says: ✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I have run the commands you have listed on there but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Junior might be certain packages were missing when you downloaded....try re-downloading it....

Comment: @V PRAVEEN KUMAR let me try that and then let you know... Thanks