# Error in Apache cordova in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

whenever i am trying to build my program in Apache Cordova in Visual studio 2015, i have been given the following errors -

1.Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.

2.Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

how can i fix this problem ? anyone have any suggestion for me.

Comment: You can try setting ANDROID_HOME via the command prompt [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

Comment: Try setting ANDROID_HOME in system environment variables and add the path of android sdk folder in Path system environment variable

Comment: is there any way to set path location in cordova project ?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the **Tools | Options... | Tools for Apache Cordova | Environment Variable Options** menu. Then, check the ADT_HOME box and make sure the file path there points at your local install of the Android SDK.

Comment: I am getting the same. I did not install any sdk outside of VS 2015. How can I check where it was installed to? Thanks

Comment: First, let's make sure that you have an Android SDK installed. In the "Programs and Features" control panel, please find Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 and choose the "Change" button. Then, in the list of installed components do you have the Android SDK checked as an option and showing as installed?