# Cannot emulate or build ionic app

Tags: android, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit, I have an ionic project and i have already Android installed, but when trying to emulate or run as Android i get these errors

> Running command:
>   /home/fathi/ionic/favorlinks/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
>   /home/fathi/ionic/favorlinks add to body class: platform-android
>   Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting
>   setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'.
>   Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I have tried to modify ~/.bashrc file by adding this

> export ANDROID_HOME=/home/fathi/Android/Sdk

But, i still getting the same errors

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful

Answer (score 0):

You are not including the `ANDROID_HOME` in `PATH`. Add the following code snippet in your `~/.bashrc`.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/fathi/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Note: Make sure to source the `~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal.

Comment: I still getting the same error:                                                             Running command: /home/fathi/ionic/favorlinks/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/fathi/ionic/favorlinks
add to body class: platform-android
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and `echo $PATH` ?

Comment: echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/fathi/Android/Sdk
echo $PATH
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/fathi/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/fathi/Android/Sdk/platform-tools

Comment: when i type android, it opens the Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0):

After trying and installing many things, I fixed it by typing this command

`sudo visudo`

and then adding this line

```
Defaults    env_keep +="ANDROID_HOME"
```

at the end of the file.