# Android AVD - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, appium

I'm new to setting up android emulator and Appium. I installed android SDK and appium.

Added the following in Windows Path

`'ANDROID_HOME',
'ANDROID_HOME'\tools, 
'ANDROID_HOME'\buildtools,
'ANDROID_HOME'\platform_tools, 
'JAVA_HOME'\bin`

When I run 'android avd' from command line getting the following error however it successfully launched "Android Virtual Device" application.

`The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.`

Any thoughts on how to fix the issue?

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I believe Windows PATH variables usually take "%", rather than " ' ". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful

Comment: You are right. Actually, path is prefixed with '%' in environment variable, I posted without 'em.