# CMD acting weird. NOT DETECTING ANDROID_HOME Even If it is set

Tags: android, sdk, phonegap-cli

This is something weird,

first I set ANDROID_HOME in environment variable, and phonegap CLI was working properly, after that I installed android studio. It asked me to avoid ANDROID HOME path with spaces(I had space in path like: *`D:\Backup data\Android\sdk`*), then I removed space and updated the environment variables, both ANDROID_HOME AND PATH.

Now When I tried to run phonegap build android I get

```
The SDK Directory D:\Backup data\Android\sdk does not exist.
```

I tried setting it through cmd prompt as given here.

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)

But did not work either.
Also tried restarting the system and setting the variable in system variable section of environment variables.

Please guide me on this.

The new path is D:\Backupdata\Android\sdk, Backupdata is without space.

Comment: I have removed the space between "Backup" and "data" for android studio. so now it is "D:\Backupdata\Android\sdk", without spaces. but in the error it is still showing old path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, 
for Phonegap android users,

the path is set in {Yourapp}\platforms\android, in the local.properties file.

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Backupdata\\Android\\sdk
```

like this.

This was because first time I ran android studio the path was the old one with space, but after changing the path(without space), I never opened android studio, As this file is automatically generated by android studio.

Now it will be again overwritten by android studio next time I run it.

Hope this helps some one.