# Environment variable issue in build an apk in ionic project

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to build an apk in ionic 2 but while building is getting following error.

**Error**:

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
>   Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

After that, I set the environment variable and path. Even though still am getting that error again can anyone please help me how to solve this issue

Comment: you are in windows ? clearly the path is not set correctly. Wat did yo set the path as?

Comment: windows only and path is "android-sdk\tools" and "android-sdk\build-tools"

Comment: what is android_home set as?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful

Comment: "C:\Android\sdk"  set as ANDROID_HOME

Comment: you have 2 different sdks?

Comment: No only one sdk

Comment: does echo %ANDROID_HOME% work?

Comment: ya its working its displaying the sdk path

Comment: what is the output of `cordova requirements`?

Comment: now it's woking fine. I just delete the path and create again then it works fine. And thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: no problem. some weird bug : ) glad it worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instruction 1:** 
After adding your ANDROID_HOME, make sure you do the below:

1. Restart your System or run source ~/.bash_profile
2. Remove Android platform from your project ionic cordova platform rm android or ionic platform rm android
3. Add Android platform ionic cordova platform add android
4. Then ionic cordova run android or ionic run android

**Instruction 2:** 
To set your ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME, follow the below steps:

1. Run command open ~/.bash_profile
2. Paste the below in the file that opens on your Text editor

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

3. Save  -  "Command S" or "Ctrl S"
4. Then Follow the "Instruction 1:" above

**NOTE: Make sure you have 24.4.1_1 SDK**

Hope this helps.