# React-native run-android failing

Tags: android, react-native

I have been stuck for two days now, I am trying to setup `react-native`, everything is in place: Up to-date Android Studio, Genymotion, paths and I followed all the guidance on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html.

When I run `"react-native run-android"` or `"react-native start"`, I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Bot>react-native run-android
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   child_process.js:512
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\setup_env.bat
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:489:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:509:13)
at Object.run (C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/Bot/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:136:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:117:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

> C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Bot>react-native start
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   child_process.js:512
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\setup_env.bat
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:489:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:509:13)
at Object.run (C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/Bot/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:136:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:117:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
```

Comment: Finally managed by commenting the line on C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/Bot/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:136:16

Answer (score 0):

Commenting a line on a file that is clearly configuring the react native client is a very bad idea. Try creating a new project from scratch. Maybe you forgot a step or the download broke and you have files missing.

Comment: Sometimes you have to edit the framework, don't be afraid to do it and remember react-native is still young so there may be bugs there too.

Comment: Did you check which line you commented? Its the one that pre configures the whole react-native-cli....

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere the environmental path for the react-native command didn't get set correctly.

Did you install the react-native-CLI globally? Like:

$ npm install **-g** react-native-cli

Make sure the path to the Java variable is set properly.
Right-click the start menu and select: 
  system->Advanced system settings->environmental variables...
The path should go to the bin folder in the JDK.

Also, make sure your ANDROID_HOME variable is set properly.
See this question:

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must-ful)