# cordova run android failed due to android studio

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have already installed Android Studio on my PC. when I try to install cordova to my PC which returns following error message. Can anyone help on this issue without reinstall Android SDK?

npm install -g cordova

cordova create MyApp

cd MyApp

cordova platform add android

when run this command returns following result :
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^7.0.0 (node:342704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Platform android already added. (node:342704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

cordova run android

when run this command returns following result :
Android Studio project detected
(node:340732) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Detected 'adb' command at C:\adb but no 'platform-tools' directory found near.
Try reinstall Android SDK or update your PATH to include valid path to SDK\platform-tools directory.
(node:340732) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the [Environment_variable user variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuzJv.png) and restart your android studio. It might be solve your problem.

[set System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RUOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set **ANDROID_HOME** in **Environment** and also **User** variable path where your android-sdk installed.

Such as **C:\Users\yourUser\android-sdks**

Follow this my problem is solved [follow this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must).