# How to custom install NativeScript ios/Android requirement in D drive?

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-cli

I am trying to install NativeScript ios/Android requirements using the command:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://www.nativescript.org/setup/win'))"
```

as per the *Step 3 of Quick Setup* guide - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/quick-setup

The command installs Android SDK and Java utilities in C drive. However, I already have all the Android SDK, Android Emulator and Java utilities installed in D drive for my native app development environment.

How can I make NativeScript use the existing Android environment instead of duplicating everything else in C drive?

Moreover, I want to keep C drive for more system specific programs, so I have dedicated D drive for all my dev works and setup.

Answer (score 1):

Nativescript looks up this from path data. Point your path variables for `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` and other related paths to the existing folder in D drive. Nativescript will then not reinstall these to `C` drive again.

For more details on how to add path variables, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356482/7049436) stackoverflow answer.