# Xamerin UI Test project is not executing in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator, ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to automate UI testing of Xamarin forms (Android app emulator) using  Xamarin.UI.Tests and Visual Studio 2017.

I created a "Xamarin.UI.Test" project and write a test cases.  But Xamarin.UI.Tests are not running when I trying to run the test using visual studio 2017. When trying to run "debug all test" project will start in debug mode and stop immediately. There is no error in error console or output window of VS2017

Comment: What does it say in the output window?

Comment: Also, do you see your tests in the test explorer?

Comment: The output window is blank nothing happening there.

Comment: Yes I can see tests in test explorer

Comment: You can [set a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2017) in the first line of your setup method, then right-click on the test in the Text Explorer and click "Debug test". That way, you will know whether the test even launches or not.

Comment: Yes did that, but project will start in debug mode and stop suddenly without hitting breakpoint

Comment: Do I need to refer the Android project in UITest project?

Comment: In that case, it's probably an exception that occurs. In the output window, there's a drop-down where you can switch between different output streams. Did you check all of them for any output? Also, have a look at the Errors tab which indicates any compilation issues.

Comment: No, referencing the Android Project is not necessary

Comment: There nothing showing in "test" output stream. I also checked the error tab.

Comment: I will try to upload test cases to App center and try to run the test there

Comment: @vatbub I have  modified the the Setup method to access the ".apk" file. now the start running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test not running issue is fix.

*I have added ".apk" file path in Test setup method. Now the Test will run and got another error regarding the android sdk not found.*

```
        [SetUp]
        public void BeforeEachTest()
        {
            app = ConfigureApp
              .Android
              .ApkFile(@"..\..\..\HelloWorldXamarinForm\HelloWorldXamarinForm.Android\
                        bin\Debug\App.HelloWorldXamarinForm.apk")
              .StartApp();
        }
```

**Hope [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must) will fix the Android SDK path issue**