# Robotium Recording Failed

Tags: robotium, robotium-recorder

I have installed the Robotium recorder plugin in Android studio and tried to record some steps by clicking on New Robotium Test button. As per the steps, I have included my APK in the file path destination. When I click on new Robotium test, It shows an error:

Recording failed. Please see output \Users\admin\Robotium_log.txt

Following is the text file of Robotium_log.txt. When i open it displays the text as shown below:

> Input:
>
> /Users/admin/Documents/SqlDatabase/gradlew -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
>   assembleDebugAndroidTest -u -b
>   /Users/admin/Documents/SqlDatabase/executorproject/build.gradle
>
> Output:
>
> Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run
>   with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.  FAILURE:
>   Build failed with an exception.  * Where: Build file
>   '/Users/admin/Documents/SqlDatabase/executorproject/build.gradle'
>   line: 54  * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root
>   project 'executorproject'. > SDK location not found. Define location
>   with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME
>   environment variable.  * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the
>   stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Run with --scan to get full insights.  * Get more help at
>   https://help.gradle.org  Deprecated Gradle features were used in this
>   build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   BUILD FAILED in 3s

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.

F.e. like this: 
[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

Comment: ANDROID_HOME is already set. I have checked that.
Am i need to set any srcDir path in my build.gradle file

Comment: I would say, that `ANDROID_HOME` variable is not set properly, from the build fail message...