# React Native 0.59 development build fails with metro server error

Tags: android, react-native

After upgrade to 0.59 the development build fails with the following error. It worked fine till 0.58.6

"Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle is packaged correctly for release."

I have also added `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml but it still won't work. The release build works fine though.

[image]

Comment: try to clean run `./gradlew clean` from android folder once to clean up previous builds and run again

Comment: Have tried that already, have even cleared node_modules folder but it still won't work.

Comment: is this the release version you are trying or development version ? if development is metro packager bundle terminal started when you run the command ?

Comment: Its the development version i am trying to build and yes metro package bundler starts correctly but got stuck at "Loading dependency graph..."

Comment: I had the same issue , this link removed my problem :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441230/unable-to-load-script-make-sure-you-are-either-running-a-metro-server-or-that-yo/59022921#59022921

Answer (score 8):

You need to change your target sdk to **27** instead of **28** in your project level `build.gradle`. From *Android P(28)*, Google ban the use of http.

[image]

Comment: Have tried it now with sdk 27, still throwing the same error.

Comment: @Ehsan - did you run gradle clean and resync your gradle files after the change to the sdk target?

Comment: @powerup7 yes, have cleared the gradle cache and other stuff but it is still showing the same error. I also created a new RN project just to test and it throws the same error. There seems to be some issue with 0.59 version

Comment: @Ehsan trying running `npm run start --reset-cache` to clear your cache. If it doesn't work then you need to bundle an bundle file for android offline.

Comment: I encountered the same issue... did anyone solved it ? using 0.59.1

Comment: Is this resolved ? I am also getting the same error. React native version that I am using is 0.59.3.

Comment: Follow this link and add ANDROID_HOME properly. It will work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue using genymotion and then I realized that the emulator was offline, and that's why it couldn't connect to the metro server.

Answer (score 0):

"react-native": "0.64.1",

I used other solution but I've resolved this issue in other way, with changing `bundleInDebug: true,` in `project.ext.react` in `android > app > build.gradle`.

```
project.ext.react = [
bundleInDebug: true,
enableHermes: ***,
```

]