# nativescript errorPubNub call failed, check status for details

Tags: angular, angular6, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I set NativeScriptwithn angular 6 and every dependency is properly installed but got the below error with these steps

1) **tns run --bundle**

2) **after that select option Sync to Playground**

3) **scan the QR code in playground app in my android mobile**

4) **show status: Successfully sent initial files for platform Android.**

after that can see this error

`Error: PubNub call failed, check the status for details
    at new PubNubError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/pubnub/lib/core/components/core/components/endpoint.js:8:31)
    at onResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/pubnub/lib/core/components/core/components/endpoint.js:126:32)
    at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/pubnub/lib/networking/modules/networking/modules/web-node.js:59:17)
    at Request.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:728:3)
    at RequestBase._timeoutError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:676:8)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:685:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)`

Also I can see some warning after the run project with command `tns run --bundle`

1)The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points to a non-existent directory. You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.

2) WARNING: adb from the Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.

3)WARNING: The Android SDK is not installed or is not configured properly.

4) Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to build for Android, install Android SDK 28 or later. 
 Run `$ sdkmanager` to manage your Android SDK versions.

5) You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=28'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue 
this issue is set the environment on Ubuntu systems 
I provide the link and follow all instruction and command 
https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-install-linux.html
I hope everyone uses this link and solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not properly set. You may follow recommedations from this question to set it up on different OSs. At least it will remove warnings that you recieved.

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

Comment: you are right Daniel 
but this solution for windows system, not ubuntu

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed that you are writing about ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error.

My procedure is as follow

1. I just create my NativeScript app by typing `tns create appName --ng`
2. Then I tried to open the app with typing `tns preview`

Forgot and the problem is with missing to install **Latest NativeScriptCLI**

Fixed with executing the `npm install -g nativescript@latest` at the directory