# Appium code is always asking for setting ANDROID_HOME, How to verify whether i set the path or not

Tags: appium

Appium code is always asking for setting ANDROID_HOME. I set it in windows environment variables but not sure whats the issue. Is there any way to check whether settings are working or not ?

Comment: Open a command window, and type `SET ANDROID_HOME` and hit enter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ANDROID\_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use appium-doctor and set your environment accordingly. If you are using eclipse set ANDROID_HOME in eclipse too. Right click on the class where you are running and under the run configure the environment tab with ANDROID_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful package [appium-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium-doctor) to verify if your environment is properly setup and meets Appium requirements for each platform.

Install it:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
```

Use it:

```
appium-doctor --android
```

It will show what exactly is missing.