# Xamarin.forms UI testing problem with android sdk

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to Ui test my app but get this error[image]

I added the environment variable
[image]

Can someone help me? i have this problem for about 3 hours now...
I'm trying to use my own android phone not an emulator

Comment: Have you try to set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable through Control Panel?

Comment: How exactly?...

Comment: Check the link below. It provides the details for how to set the `ANDROID_HOME` variable through Control Panel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Normally, we could fix the error with the suggestions provided. Try to repair the VS and reinstall the SDKs.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this,

Goto Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Check if the option is enabled for `Auto Install Android SDK`

Click on `OK` then just try clean & rebuild your application.

[image]

the issue might have occurred cuz you might have downloaded SDK version for API levels 20, 21, 22 etc. but your project target SDK version is set on API level 28