# Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'android' using Ionic Framework 5.x in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Ionic 5.x in order to build a hybrid mobile app.  The problem that I am facing is that when I use gradle to manually build the app I get the following error:

`Task 'assembleDebug' not found in root project 'android'.`

I have searched and could not find a solution to this issue.  How do I go about fixing this error as I can't get the mobile app to install on the Android Virtual Device (AVD)?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: ANDROID\_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error.  I made sure after updating to run ```source ~/.bashrc``` and I also did the same thing with ```~/.bash_profile```.

Comment: are you able to just run the emulator by itself? Have you installed an AVD?

Comment: Yes, AVD is installed and I am running it through Android Studio.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is deleting platforms, node_modules, and www. Do a `npm ci` and then `cordova prepare && cordova platform add android` Doesn't hurt to try burning down and resetting the build files.