# problems when running the ionic cordova build android command

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I don't know how to soluicon the problem, I've tried everything, please help.
[image]

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.  The error would indicate that you do not have Java SDK 1.8 installed. Is it so?

Comment: If I have it installed and it appears to me like no. I uninstalled the Andriod Studio, reinstalled it, installed the recent version of node, the gradle, I have configured the environment variables and nothing, I do not know what else I can do.

Comment: Try running this command and respond back with a cut and paste of the result. `cordova requirements android --verbose`

Comment: From your screen shot it looks like you are using windows so please also report the result from `echo %path%`

Answer (score 0):

From the error it appears that you have neither Java nor Android Studio installed,
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT & ANDOID_HOME are both undefined!

Try it:

[Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356359/error-android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-you-must)