# Flutter file_picker package error while building app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-file

I have created a flutter app and part of the requirements is selecting files from storage. I have settled on the `file_picker 3.0.1` package for this due to several tutorials using it. However I encounter a problem while trying to run my app. I have not even started using the package. Here is the error I get

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\Hp\FlutterProjects\flutter_application_test\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5m 31s
```

This is another error that i get also

```
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin file_picker...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'file_picker'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 12s
```

This is the `pubspec.yaml` file

```
name: flutter_application_test
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  http: ^0.13.1
  json_annotation: ^4.0.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  flutter_slidable: ^0.6.0-nullsafety.0
  animations: ^2.0.0
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.5
  permission_handler: ^7.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.2
  file_picker: ^3.0.1
  flutter_rounded_date_picker: ^2.0.1

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.11.5
  json_serializable: ^4.1.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "images/pcl2.png"

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
    
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: please share screenshot of your `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Even better if you paste your `pubspec.yaml` into the question. Code screenshots are hard to search and read.

Comment: Setup the ANDROID_HOME variable in your system.

Comment: @JorgeVieira how do I set that up?

Comment: Here an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356482/2831595

Comment: @JorgeVieira I tried and it's not working.

Comment: Is your project migrated to AndroidX? "The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin"

Comment: @JorgeVieira Yes it is. I think it is a gradle issue. I changed gradle version in ```gradle-wrapper.properties``` to 5.6.4-all.zip and build was successful